# How to know if a hard drive is physically damaged?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently ordered a hard drive (platter HDD not SSD) online. It was shipped in the post. Is there a way to test it to see if it's been damaged or dropped ?

If it boots fine the first time with no noises does that mean it's fine or are there some other tests I can run?

Im running OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the integrity of the hard drive both in Window 10 and in macOS by doing the following:

#### Windows 10:

1. Open CMD.
2. Check the S.M.A.R.T status is OK (this indicates the hardrive doesn't have any harware errors, and will survive chkdsk). In order to do that, type the following

   ```
   wmic diskdrive get status
   ```
3. If it's OK, then type the following:

   ```
   chkdsk [volume[[path]filename]]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]]
   ```

   - **Volume** Sets the volume to work with.
   - **filename** FAT/FAT32 only: Specifies files to check for fragmentation.
   - **/F** Fixes errors on the disk.
   - **/V** On FAT/FAT32, this displays the full path and name of every file on the disk.    On NTFS, this displays cleanup messages, if any.
   - **/R** Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information (implies /F).
   - **/L:size** NTFS only. Changes the log file size.
   - **/X** Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary (implies /F).
   - **/I** NTFS only. Performs a minimum check of index entries.
   - **/C** NTFS only. Skips checking of cycles within the folder structure.

For example, this will check drive `D` and then correct the errors (if there has any):

```
chkdsk D: /f /r
```

#### macOS:

1. Go to Disk Utility (on the utilities folder) and select the drive you wanna check (the drive, not the volume indented below it)
2. Check that S.M.A.R.T status shows "verified" (this means the hard drive doesnt have any harware errors)
3. In the First aid tab, click "Verify" to check the directory structure, and "Repair permissions" to check permissions on system files (this may generate a lot of error messages, but they can be ignored)

Comment: actually you want **chkdsk /R** as it checks for bad sectors **/f** only checks the table of contents.

Comment: @cybernard, be careful to check the SMART stats both before and after running chkdsk. not only do current pending sectors turn into reallocated sectors after running chkdsk, we want to make sure the disk is healthy enough to survive the chkdsk. if its truely on its last legs, you want to use that remaining life for imaging it, before it goes belly up. got bit by that once.